# How to write a makefile for python, R and bash scripts

Tags: makefile

I am a statistician, and I recently wrote an bash pipeline for a research project, it is basically a main bash scripts calling bash, python and R scripts at each step of analysis, and there are lots of steps and lots scripts of course. My friend told me that I can create a makefile for them, but I have little experience on computer except writing scripts. I found somes examples but they are for VC. Does my cases also need to compile like VC programs? Can anyone share me some of his experience?
For example, I have main.sh, which calls step1.py, step2.sh, step3.r, and step2.sh calls step2.1.py, step2.2.r how do I link them by makefile?

Comment: No, you do not need to compile Python, R or Bash scripts. What do you think you need a Makefile for?

Comment: Make is well suited to making files (though it can do other things). It's especially good at making files in a DAG, when the output file of one process is the input file of another; if someone has modified some of the input files, Make will *figure out which steps are needed to bring everything up to date*, and carry them out. If that sounds like your situation, we'll be happy to help you; otherwise, Make is not an especially good tool for your job and there's no reason to adopt it.

Comment: Make as a language provides some very powerful macro/text substition mechanisms. Even if your code is not manipulating any data on file, I've found that using Make as a layer/coordinator on top of Bash is quite powerful. If if seems that there is a complex web of dependencies between each of your scripts, and you'd like to express those dependencies in a file that sits a layer above all of those scripts, then IMO Make might actually work quite well for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
step1: 
     step1.py;\
     $(MAKE) step2;\
     step3.r

step2:
     step2.1.py;\
     step2.2.r

all: step1
     echo "Done"
```

From your description, it sounds like main.sh and step2.sh just call the python and R scripts. If so, then the above is the Makefile that would replace them. If they have other steps in them, then you can add those bash commands in the step1 or step2 targets.

Using a Makefile like this will allow you to also execute only part of your execution sequence for debugging purposes.